# Объем понятия "стойка"

Tags: лексика

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно ли назвать деталь, связывающую видеоискатель с трубой "стойкой"? Вообще одним из принятых для этой небольшой детали названий является "держатель", но мне интересны варианты. Какую степень широты имеет понятие "стойка"? Она может быть разных размеров, соединять части механизмов?

P. S. Если что, на картинке - телескоп

Answer (score 2):

Стойка - *вертикальная* конструкция для крепления чего-либо. Здесь подойдёт "держатель" или "кронштейн".